# How to backup/export additionally downloaded components via SDK Manager

Tags: android, sdk, adt

My internet is limited and I want to backup the components (eg: Google USB Driver) that I've downloaded via SDK Manager, so that later I can reinstall those if needed when I'll be offline.
Is there are any way to do this?